# Why does the descriptor extraction from vectors of images fail (OpenCV)?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

The problem is the behaviour of feature extractors in openCV if one wants to extract descriptors of several images at the same time. The cv::DescriptorExtractor offers two interfaces for that:

```
void DescriptorExtractor::compute(const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors) const
void DescriptorExtractor::compute(const vector<Mat>& images, vector<vector<KeyPoint>>& keypoints, vector<Mat>& descriptors) const
```

I am talking about the second signature which allows to pass a sequence of images. I tested the behaviour with the following minimal example:

```
#include"opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2\xfeatures2d\nonfree.hpp"

int main(){

    //Read image
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("./sample.png");
    //Create vector of images
    std::vector<cv::Mat> imageSequence(10, img);
    //Create SIFT detector and extractor
    cv::FeatureDetector* detector = new cv::xfeatures2d::SiftFeatureDetector();
    cv::DescriptorExtractor* extractor = new cv::xfeatures2d::SiftDescriptorExtractor();
    //Keypoints
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>> keypoints;
    //Compute keypoints
    detector->detect(imageSequence, keypoints);
    //This vector should contain all descriptors
    std::vector<cv::Mat> allDescriptors;
    //Version 1: Using a for loop and the single image signature of DescriptorExtractor::compute works.
    for (int i = 0; i < imageSequence.size(); ++i){
        cv::Mat descriptors;
        //This compute(...) works
        extractor->compute(imageSequence.at(i), keypoints.at(i), descriptors);
        allDescriptors.push_back(descriptors);
    }

    allDescriptors.clear();
    //Version 2: Using the interface for the computation of descriptors for std::vector<cv::Mat> fails
    extractor->compute(imageSequence, keypoints, allDescriptors);

    return 0;
}
```

While Version 1 in the example above returns the descriptors for all images correctly, the Version 2 does not - the variable allDescriptors is empty. However, when I step into the compute function I can observe that it calls the compute function with the single image signature in a for loop but the original variable allDescriptors is unaffected. I am working with the latest 3.0 version of opencv from the git repository.
There is another issue with the DescriptorExtractor::compute function. The SiftDescriptorExtractor inherits from Feature2D which inherits again from DescriptorExtractor and FeatureDetector. Feature2D overwrites only

```
void DescriptorExtractor::compute(const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors) const
```

and not the overload of compute which accepts the image sequences. According to Scott Meyers, "Effective C++", Item 33, this shades the second overload of compute. Therefore, the second overload is not available if I change the pointer from the base class type cv::DescriptorExtractor* to cv::xfeatures2d::SiftDescriptorExtractor - the compiler will complain that there is no overload of compute with the correct signature. I am not sure if this behaviour is intended. Thanks for any advice how to make DescriptorExtractor::compute(...) work for vectors of images!

Comment: you are passing in a empty vector for the descriptors, the documentation is not very clear and I don't have a way to test it. But you may need to allocate space in your vector, for example a vector of 10 defaulted constructed cv::Mat. I think, the item of Effective C++ has little to do with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I tried resizing the vector before calling compute and initializing it with cv::Mat. It won't help. I also think the shading does not cause the problem that the descriptors are not correctly returned. However, it is a problem which occurs in this context if one directly constructs a SiftDescriptorExtractor object and tries to call compute(...) with multiple images - the compiler will complain.

Comment: Are you sure that std::vector<cv::Mat> imageSequence(10, img); is initialized correctly. I don't know the documentation but looks for me like the vector has the size of 10 but only get one Image, img. You should try to use the an cv:Mat[] with 10 images.

Comment: @PeterNL looks correct to me, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector the constructor create a vector with 10 elements all equal to the initial element provided.

Comment: Its initialized correctly. I think its a bug of opencv - the descriptors are computed inside compute(...) within a for loop (see descriptors.cpp line 78 of opencv). However, they are not stored at the memory location of allDescriptors and are lost after return.